# How to find skilled people to start a company

Tags: startup

I have an idea that I would like to monetize through a startup company (software based). Although I have the technical skills and a working prototype it is simply too much work for a single person to do. I would therefore like to get some people to join me as partners and not as employees (unfortunately I do not have the funds yet to hire people).
The problem is that  I don't know how to start in order to find people to join my startup idea. Everyone I talked to about it really likes the whole concept but most skilled people are busy with their full time jobs.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could go about starting such a project? Any startup (technical/AI) forums that you might suggest that would be good starting points?

Answer (score 6):

> Everyone I talked to about it really likes the whole concept but most skilled people are busy with their full time jobs.

Are you sure they like the idea? I'm very busy with my full time job but if I genuinely thought it was going to be a success I'd make time. Maybe ask someone who isn't your friend to get a more honest opinion.

There are entrepreneur meetup groups - I'd try going to those and talking to folks there. If they like the idea maybe they will help.

Comment: I think it is more basic than that. Obviously if you have a working solution with years of proof-of-concept data and profit it is easier to get people on board, rather than with an idea and a prototype. People will think about the risks involved. The question is having the latter how do you go about finding some partners with equal or better skills. Its a fundamental problem

Comment: @vzografos are you looking for partners or investors? You absolutely don't need a proof-of-concept for finding engineering partners. If they buy into the idea they can help you build it you just need to show them your vision and convince them it's worth their time.

Comment: I am looking for partners. Investors are easier to find in my experience. Regarding showing them your vision and convincing them how do you suggest one does that? I always found it easier to convince people with hard evidence e.g. a proof of concept, historical performance data etc.

Comment: @vzografos you can show them your research and your business plan. I think x will solve problem y which people will pay for because <insert research>. You don't need any code or assets for this. A very simple test that I like to do is to run ads that bring people to a landing page, track if people are leaving their email for updates on the project. If you arent getting any clicks or emails, nobody is interested.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a working prototype, but a prototype does not a business make.

I think you are asking people who have the wrong skills.

There are three skills needed to have a software business: the visionary, the sales person, and the developer. At this point, you have a vision, but you do not mention who you have as the sales person. If you look at the history of Apple Computer, they had the visionary who was also a sales person. They had a developer. And they had an experienced business person running things behind the scenes.

Without a sales person, you don't have a business. Without customers, you do not have a business.

Now, you could be that sales person. It would take you going out and "cold calling" on potential clients and trying to sell to them. If you can sell a customer on using your prototype, that would be a sign that you might have a business.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need employees yet, you need an investor - somebody who sees enough of a future in you and your product to put their money into it to allow you to build the company. Once you have that, then you can look at hiring more people.

A good investor will also have the contacts you need to help you get the business going.